# How to setup correctly iPad Launch Images in xCode 4.2 for both orientations

Tags: xcode, ipad, orientation

Ok. So I have iPad app in Xcode 4.2 targeted for iOS 5.1. I provided it with launch images for both landscape and portrait modes and it has some serious trouble with using them properly.

First in landscape mode it shows proper landscape image but rotated by 90 degrees CW and cropped on the right side. Then when it starts to display it properly but does it also in portrait mode (as if it doesn't recognize portrait mode at all anymore).

I've seen some suggestions like providing portrait image with rotated content for landscape mode, etc. but the problem is I can't for the life of me make xCode use both images in right moments.

Is there some voodoo for that? Like setting them in proper order, use plist directly or the slots in GUI, putting them in some special directory or two different directories, I don't know - anything? Fighting xCode over such things will make me puke with blood one day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, one thing to know is that xCode seems to be very capricious when it comes to updating settings, resources etc. I deleted references to the launch images from the project, cleaned the product in xCode and removed the app from simulator but it still somehow managed to use the launch images even though it didn't show copying the images in build log.

I'm not sure if it took the pictures from derived data or what but I had to delete derived data and remove the images manually from the app bundle in ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications/ to make it stop. Then I pasted the images manually   into the app bundle and now after publishing both images work properly in the simulator ignoring the fact that I didn't set them up at all in xCode!

I'm still not sure how to proceed with the device version - it obviously doesn't have the launch images now...

---

Apparently xCode doesn't care at all about setting anything about the launch images apart from including properly named images in the project so they get copied to the bundle. As I wrote above you can even inject the images into the app bundle and it still works.

The other side is that once you get the images there it may by hard to get rid of them.

So anyway now I have nothing in my plist about the images, nor anything in the slots in the Target Info and I have four working launch images in my app (both orientations and retina).

Hope it helps someone sometime..